# Duplicate tags: russia and russian-federation

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

<s>Despite of the growing interest caused by their plans of breaking a global war against the entire world,</s>
I think the country does not deserve two tags [russia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia) and [russian-federation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-federation). Suggesting to keep only one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[russia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia) is a bad tag (it's ambiguous as it can be referring to pre-1917 Russia AND it's not reflecting the actual name of the country but its colloquial name). It also has only 5 questions 100% of which are indeed about Russian Federation.

As such:

- all questions with [russia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia) need to be retagged as [russian-federation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-federation)
- [russia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia) needs to be made a synonym of [russian-federation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-federation) going forward.