# UN or United-Nations?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have a [un](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/un) and a [united-nations](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-nations).  Overall, I think that united-nations is clearer, but UN has a wiki excerpt and more questions and followers.  There are only [three questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-nations+un) that are tagged with both, and I believe that one would be sufficient on those three.

I would like to copy the wiki and excerpt from UN to united-nations and then make UN as synonym for united-nations (such that UN will be replaced with united-nations).  I have privileges enough to at least start those processes.  I'm not sure what happens with the followers in that case, as I've never done it.  I believe the questions get migrated.

My question is if there is any reason why I should not do that?  Either to keep them separate or to go the other direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I copied the tag wiki and then merged the tag [un](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/un) into [united-nations](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-nations) using the mod interface. This should retag all the questions, create a tag synonym and also update any subscriptions.

```
Merge Results

updating post history, 51 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 41 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 38 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [united-nations] and [un] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
6 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym un -> united-nations was approved!
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem. A similar case was about the [russia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russia) and [russian-federation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-federation) tags, see details [here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/duplicate-tags-russia-and-russian-federation).

I've been also subscribed to the RSS feed containing the former tag globally across the SE network, and I keep receiving notifications for Politics.SE questions tagged the latter one.